# Elasticsearch - Migrate data from one large index to many time-based indicies

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, opensearch

We have one large index on 5 shards on a 5.5 cluster.  Each shard has several hundred GB of time-series data.  It's not log data for debugging, we're serving production requests doing aggregations on the documents.  So we need solid read performance on these aggregations, and enough indexing performance to keep up with the flow of new records.

Most of the aggregation queries probably need to only go over a subset of the data (e.g. the last 30 days of it), so we'd like to migrate the data to an index configuration where we have one index per day, or something similar so that we can increase the number of indexes / shards and scale more horizontally.

How do you migrate your data from one large index to 500 daily indexes?  I don't see an API in ES that lets you do this.  Can ILM do this during a re-index?

Comment: fyi 5.5 is super old and no longer supported. you really need to upgrade as we just released 8.0, which makes 6.X EOL

Comment: yea that's something we want to do as a part of this change.

Answer (score 0):

if it's time based data, logs or something else, then treat it the same and use time based indices

ILM is the best longer term approach here, but a reindex into an ILM index/policy won't really work as it works of index ages, not the age of data in those indices

you could do a historic reindex into time based indices, and then point new data into an ILM policy, that'd be the best approach

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what "you could do a historic reindex into time based indices" means?  That's the crux of what I'm asking...what the mechanics of how to do this?

Comment: sure. setup an ilm policy, then use the reindex api to pull from the old indices and into the new ilm write alias. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/docs-reindex.html goes into it, but again use the ilm alias in the destination and you will be good

Comment: Great, thanks! I guess I'm confused by what you said above against this -- you said that re-indexing into an index template managed by ILM won't move the data into separate time-based indexes because it works off of 'index age' vs. the data.

How do you reindex my large index into all the small 1-day indexes? 1,000 reindexes with filters / queries attached?  Or can ILM help?

Comment: ILM rollover is based on the age that the index holding the data was created on. so even if you reindex data from 6 months ago into your ILM policy, and your policy said "delete after 3 months", cause that index is just new you'd end up having the data in the index around for 9 months

Comment: Ok, thanks!  That's what I understood your answer to say.  I'm still hopeful you have a suggestion on how we can actually port the data from one big index to 1,000 daily indexes?

Comment: you need to reindex to the ILM write alias and it'll handle it